# Expat returning to the UK with German husband who is retired

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration, family

I have been living in Germany for over 30 years with my German husband. We were married in the UK. My husband has a German pension. What happens with our health care when we return? I have not paid into the system since I left. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

NHS entitlement is based on lawful settled residence, not contributions.

As a resident citizen you will be entitled to healthcare, assuming you will be returning to live in the UK and not just visiting.

I can't comment on your husband as I am not sure how the free movement directive as applied to retirees, reciprocal healthcare agreements with Germany, and the UK leaving the EU will intersect.